# TimePicker only show minutes and setmaximum minutes if the user enter a time with the keyboard

Tags: android, timepicker

This is how my timepicker looks at the moment.
I want it to only display the minutes and the minutes only to maximum 30.
It works fine but when u enter the time with the keyboard it sets the time to 0 but i want it to go to the maximum.
so if a user enters 50 it should go to 30, how can i do this?
and how can i hide the hour of the timepicker cause it's not needed here.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    System.out.println("Powernap");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.powernap);
    TimePicker pn = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.tp_powernap);

    pn.setOnTimeChangedListener(StartTimeChangedListener);
    pn.setIs24HourView(true);
}

    private TimePicker.OnTimeChangedListener StartTimeChangedListener =
        new TimePicker.OnTimeChangedListener() {

        public void onTimeChanged(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
            updateDisplay(view, hourOfDay, minute);          
        }
    };

    private TimePicker.OnTimeChangedListener NullTimeChangedListener =
        new TimePicker.OnTimeChangedListener() {

        public void onTimeChanged(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {

        }
    };

    private void updateDisplay(TimePicker timePicker, int hourOfDay, int minute) { 

        // do calculation of next time 
        int nextMinute = 0;
        int nextHour = 0;
        if (minute > 30){
            System.out.println("Minute+30");
            nextMinute = 30;
            // set minute
            timePicker.setCurrentMinute(nextMinute);
        }
        else {          
            System.out.println("minute 0");
            nextMinute = 0;
        }
        if (hourOfDay != 0){
            System.out.println("hour>0");
            nextHour = 24;
        }

        // remove ontimechangedlistener to prevent stackoverflow/infinite loop
        timePicker.setOnTimeChangedListener(NullTimeChangedListener);

        // set minute
        timePicker.setCurrentMinute(timePicker.getCurrentMinute()+nextMinute);

        //set hour
        timePicker.setCurrentHour(nextHour);

        // hook up ontimechangedlistener again
        timePicker.setOnTimeChangedListener(StartTimeChangedListener);

    }
```

Answer (score 4):

that's how i did the part with the maximum and minimum and the 5mins steps, there are samples on stackoverflow but with their methods u can't use both the up and the down button, with my method it works:

```
public class Powernap extends Activity {



/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    System.out.println("Powernap");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.powernap);
    TimePicker pn = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.tp_powernap);
    pn.setCurrentMinute(5);
    System.out.println("timepicker erstellt");
    pn.setDescendantFocusability(TimePicker.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);
    System.out.println("Tastatur geblockt");
    pn.setOnTimeChangedListener(StartTimeChangedListener);
    System.out.println("starttimechangedlistener");
    pn.setIs24HourView(true);
}


    private TimePicker.OnTimeChangedListener StartTimeChangedListener =
        new TimePicker.OnTimeChangedListener() {

        public void onTimeChanged(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
            updateDisplay(view, hourOfDay, minute);          
        }
    };

    private TimePicker.OnTimeChangedListener NullTimeChangedListener =
        new TimePicker.OnTimeChangedListener() {

        public void onTimeChanged(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {

        }
    };

    private void updateDisplay(TimePicker timePicker, int hourOfDay, int minute) { 

        // do calculation of next time 
        int nextMinute = 0;
        int nextHour = 0;
        if (minute >= 30 && minute <= 59){
            System.out.println("Minute+30");
            nextMinute = 30;
        }
        else if(minute == 26){
            System.out.println("Minute auf 30");
            nextMinute = 30;
        }
        else if(minute == 25 || minute == 21 || minute == 29){
            System.out.println("Minute auf 25");
            nextMinute = 25;
        }
        else if(minute == 20 || minute == 16 || minute == 24){
            System.out.println("Minute auf 20");
            nextMinute = 20;
        }
        else if(minute == 15 || minute == 11 || minute == 19){
            System.out.println("Minute auf 15");
            nextMinute = 15;
        }
        else if(minute == 10 || minute == 6 || minute == 14){
            System.out.println("Minute auf 10");
            nextMinute = 10;
        }
        else if(minute == 5 || minute == 1 || minute == 9 || minute < 5){
            System.out.println("Minute auf 5");
            nextMinute = 5;
        }





        if (hourOfDay != 0){
            System.out.println("hour>0");
            nextHour = 24;
        }

        // remove ontimechangedlistener to prevent stackoverflow/infinite loop
        timePicker.setOnTimeChangedListener(NullTimeChangedListener);

        // set minute
        timePicker.setCurrentMinute(nextMinute);

        //set hour
        timePicker.setCurrentHour(nextHour);

        // hook up ontimechangedlistener again
        timePicker.setOnTimeChangedListener(StartTimeChangedListener);

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You will need to write your own widget. What you want is not supported by the `TimePicker` widget or `TimePickerDialog`.

Comment: only to hide the hour, or also to display only the minutes to 30. another thing i want to do is to display only the 5,10,15,20,25 and 30 mins with the button up and down. i only found a solution to do it with the up or the down and the other isn't workin.

Comment: @kirbby: My answer still stands: you will have to write your own widget.

Comment: ok i got the thing with the mins from minimum 5 to maximum 30 in 5min steps, didn't write a new one ;) and i think i will ignore the hour part and let it there, because the user can't enter sth there.